# Why is "guild" not defined such as in video? | discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py, pyflakes

I'm following a video on how to change prefixes server specific. I changed it to use channels instead but now I got the problem that the name `guild` is not defined. In the video the YouTuber has got no error. What am I doing wrong?

The Code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("welcomechanels.json", "r") as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
        
    welcomechannels[str(guild.id)] = ""

    with open("welcomechannels.json", "W"):
        json.dump(welcomechannels, f)

@client.command(name="setwelcomechannel")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def setwelcomechannel(ctx, channel: discord.Channel):
    with open("welcomechannels.json", "r") as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
        welcomechannels[str(guild.id)] = channel.id
        with open("welcomechannels.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(welcomechannels, f)
    await ctx.send(f"Der Welcomechannel ist jetzt <#{channel.id}>.")
```

My Error:

[image: My Code]

His Code (https://youtu.be/Hh9MYiaV9U8?t=306):
[image: His Code]

**UPDATE:**

If someone joins the guild (server), I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 78, in on_member_join
    await channel.send(f'<:899414480314859530:927212502654255125> Willkommen, {member.mention}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

The function `on_member_join()` looks like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        guild = member.guild
        channel = guild.get_channel(get_welcomechannel(client,member))
        e = discord.Embed(title=f"Willkommen in {guild.name}", colour=0xC0EEFF, description=
f'''
{member.mention}
<a:614619624268365829:915316001401344011> Schau doch gerne mal vorbei in... <a:614619624268365829:915316001401344011> 
<a:880584719916499055:927212502570369024> <#889211881661800529>
<a:880584719916499055:927212502570369024> <#889211881288499298>
<a:880584719916499055:927212502570369024> <#889211881661800533>
<a:880584719916499055:927212502570369024> <#889211881921867866>
<a:614619624268365829:915316001401344011>  Habt Spaß auf {guild.name} und seid aktiv!<a:614619624268365829:915316001401344011>
''')
        e.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/748986660674601040/927204486307524608/6841391f576d4afcb2673b9dcc4d4dd1.gif')
        await channel.send(f'<:899414480314859530:927212502654255125> Willkommen, {member.mention}')
        await channel.send(embed=e)
```

The function `get_welcomechannel()` looks like this:

```py
def get_welcomechannel(client, message):
    with open("./welcomechannels.json", "r") as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)

    return welcomechannels[str(message.guild.id)]
```

I added the guild id and the channel id manually but I still can't change them with the command `setwelcomechannel`.

Comment: If you want the guild to be the guild someone executed the command in, simply say `ctx.guild.id`. "Guild is not defined" means you never used it in the command or depended on it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ctx.guild`. Guild isnt defined in your command because well... it doesn't know what `guild` is. You can use the `.guild` property of the `ctx` to get the guild it was in.

Also, instead of `<#{channel.id}>`, you can use the `.mention` property of a channel to to the same thing.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open("welcomechanels.json", "r") as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
        
    welcomechannels[str(guild.id)] = ""

    with open("welcomechannels.json", "W"):
        json.dump(welcomechannels, f)

@client.command(name="setwelcomechannel")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def setwelcomechannel(ctx, channel: discord.Channel):
    with open("welcomechannels.json", "r") as f:
        welcomechannels = json.load(f)
        welcomechannels[str(ctx.guild.id)] = channel.id
        with open("welcomechannels.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(welcomechannels, f)
    await ctx.send(f"Der Welcomechannel ist jetzt {channel.mention}.")
```

Comment: Instead of just putting a big block of code in, you should mention what you changed. Do [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71658015/edit) to reflect this, thanks